# 4 consecutive non-chord tones

Tags: harmony, nonchord-tones

Looking at the first measure of the chorus in Ecuador https://www.hooktheory.com/theorytab/view/sash/ecuador I have noticed that at the end of the measure there are four consecutive non-chord tones: c#-e-c#-a

All those notes are outside of bm

Looking at any list of non-chord tones (there are a lot over the internet) I don't find anything that looks like this, any one knows what kind of embellishing is this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As No'am states, it's an A major chord, often used in Bm as a sort of dominant - also the dominant of the next chord in this piece - D. Why the underlying chord stays on Bm is something only the composer knows, but because it's only there for a moment, it passes off o.k. So, no chord tones, but all notes from the Bm key. It's unusual, as most chords will have a note or two at least from that chord in the melody.Could have used an A chord - didn't.

Comment: I know the VII chord in minor, but I was confused about the notes being played over Bm so I didn't thought about it. Changing the chord in that part to A makes it sound totally different, so I guess is not really trying to imply A

Answer (score 0):

Those notes outline an A major chord, which is the bVII of Bm. This chord often appears in tunes written in minor scales.